# C# LINQ: Efficient way to set anonymous type property based on other values in query?

Tags: c#, linq

```
// The "myData" table contains two fields: name, value and type.
// The "myInfo" table contains two fields: type and value.

var myQuery = from x in myData
    select new {
        name = x.name,
        value = x.value,
        minValue = myInfo.Where(y => x.type == y.type).OrderBy(y => y.value).FirstOrDefault().value,
        isOverMinValue = (myInfo.Where(y => x.type == y.type).OrderBy(y => y.value).FirstOrDefault().value) > x.value ? true : false
    };
```

The myInfo table might contain multiple records matching the type from myData; I only want the minimum value. Then I want the isOverMinValue field to indicate whether the value in myData is greater than the minimum value found in myInfo.

In this example, it works, but as you can see I have to repeat the entire subquery twice. This can't be efficient. The alternative approach I had was:

```
var myQuery = from x in myData
    select new {
        name = x.name,
        value = x.value,
        minValue = myInfo.Where(y => x.type == y.type).OrderBy(y => y.value).FirstOrDefault().value,
        isOverMinValue = false
    };

foreach (var myRec in myQuery)
{
    if (myRec.minValue < x.Value) myRec.isOverMinValue = true;
}
```

This however won't work because it seems the properties on anonymous types are read-only.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

(I can't do a join because like I said myInfo might contain multiple entries, and doing a normal LINQ join will end up producing many records based on how many matches are found in myInfo.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `let` keyword:

```
var myQuery = from x in myData
    let minvalue = myInfo.Where(y => x.type == y.type)
                         .OrderBy(y => y.value).FirstOrDefault().value
    select new {
        name = x.name,
        value = x.value,
        minValue = minvalue,
        isOverMinValue = minvalue > x.value
    };
```

By the way, I'm not sure if you've got the `>` sign right.

Comment: Wouldn't better to assign `minvalue` this way: `let minvalue = myInfo.Where(y => x.type == y.type).Select(a=>a.value).Min()`? `OrderBy` and the rest of statement is redunant - i think.

Comment: AWESOME! Exactly what I needed. And I might have had the sign wrong, but that's another issue. :-)

Comment: @MaciejLos Didn't even look at that, but yes, I guess so, thanks. `myInfo.Where(y => x.type == y.type).Min(x => x.value)`.